# Combine asyncio websockets and QThread

Tags: websocket, pyqt, python-asyncio, qthread, event-loop

I have a pyqt app and it has to communicate via websockets with clients. I manage to create the server in a python script outside the qt environment, but when I included the asyncio.run it froze the qt app. Therefore I tried to create an inherited QThread class to handle the websocket functions :

```py
class WSThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, port, loop, parent=None):
        super(WSThread, self).__init__(parent)
        self.clients = []
        self.port = port
        self.loop = loop

    def run(self):
        server = websockets.serve(self.handler, "", self.port)
        self.loop.run_until_complete(server)
        self.loop.run_forever()

    # async def start_server(self):
    #     await self.server.wait_closed()

    async def send(self, websocket, message):
        try:
            await websocket.send(message)
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            pass

    async def broadcast(self, message):
        if self.clients:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
            await asyncio.wait([
                asyncio.create_task(self.send(websocket, message))
                for websocket in self.clients
            ])

    async def handler(self, websocket, path):
        self.clients.append(websocket)
        async for message in websocket:
            await self.broadcast(message)
```

The objective is to transmit the received message on the server to all connected clients. My code is surely not optimal but it works separately from Qt.

I use it in a QDialog class like this :

```py
class MyDialog(QDialog)
    def __init__(self, port, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.port = port

        tb = QPushButton()
        tb.setText("Start WS")
        tb.clicked.connect(self.start_ws)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(tb)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def start_ws(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        ws = WSThread(self.port, loop)
        ws.start()

dlg = MyDialog(8888)
dlg.show()
```

But I get an error message : `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-3'.`. I don't understand this message as I'm creating the loop and passing it as argument to the thread class.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I added the minimal code to create the dialog hope it's enough

Comment: 1. Sorry but that's **not** a MRE: we need a code that **allows** us to see how the problem could be reproduced (probably by allowing us to *actually* reproduce it, which normally involves some code that we can copy, paste and run, possibly without substantial modifications); 2. that `ws` object will be garbage collected; QThread doesn't work like python `Thread`, it's important that a reference to that object is persistent for the full lifespan of the thread; 3. please provide the *full* traceback of the error (try to run the code in a terminal or prompt, IDEs often show only the last part).

Comment: asyncio is not compatible with Qt's eventloop.